# Problem with WNetGetUniversalName

Tags: c++, windows-vista, unc

I have a strange problem with some code that calls WNetGetUniversalName. When I call the function I always get error 67 (ERROR_BAD_NET_NAME). But the network connection really does exist.
So from the scratch. I'm writing a Windows shell extension that shall do some stuff with text files that are located on a specified network drive. So when the IShellExtInit::Initialize method is called I store the dragged file and will then get the connection name by using the WNetGetUniversalName method.
So I can be really sure that the network drive does exist (as it comes from the DragQueryFile method).
Here's some code:

```
char buffer[4096];  
REMOTE_NAME_INFO *info = (REMOTE_NAME_INFO*)buffer;  
DWORD length = 4096;  
info->lpConnectionName = NULL;  
info->lpRemainingPath = NULL;  
info->lpUniversalName = NULL;  
DWORD error = WNetGetUniversalName(file, REMOTE_NAME_INFO_LEVEL, info, &length);
```

file is an ATL::CString that comes from the DragQueryFile method and error is always 67.
Odd thing is that it did work some days ago but not anymore, and I didn't change any of that code posted.

Comment: Have you verified the content of `file` is what you think it is? (Via debugging/Log?)

Comment: Yes, I also tried it hard coded with: DWORD dwError = WNetGetUniversalName(_T("Z:\\test.txt"), REMOTE_NAME_INFO_LEVEL, info, &dwLength); and DWORD dwError = WNetGetUniversalName(_T("Z:"), REMOTE_NAME_INFO_LEVEL, info, &dwLength);
Still same result.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little hard to guess about the problem. One possibility is that the `file` you're passing as the file name isn't formatted quite correctly. For example, even if the file is in the root shared directory, something like `z:test.txt` would not work -- it requires: `z:\\test.txt`.

The usual way to call WNetGetUniversalName involves a sequence like:

1. Call with small buffer to get required size
2. allocate proper-sized buffer
3. call again with buffer of proper size

Unlike quite a few Windows network functions, however, this one apparently checks that you've sent a non-NULL pointer with a positive size first, then checks whether the buffer is large enough for what it wants to return, so the sequence looks something like this:

```
REMOTE_NAME_INFO temp;
REMOTE_NAME_INFO *info = &temp;  
DWORD size = sizeof(temp);

// call with buffer that's valid but too small.    
WNetGetUniversalNameA("z:\\test.txt", REMOTE_NAME_INFO_LEVEL, info, &size);

// allocate large enough buffer:
info = static_cast<REMOTE_NAME_INFO *>(::operator new(size));

// call again with large enough buffer:
WNetGetUniversalNameA("z:\\test.txt", REMOTE_NAME_INFO_LEVEL, info, &size);

// Show result:
std::cout << info->lpUniversalName;
```

Comment: Sorry that didn't help. But it's getting more odd. I tried out WNetGetConnection and it did work but WNetGetUniversalName still doesn't. Nevertheless I'd like to know why WNetGetUniversalName doesn't work anymore because I'd prefer using that method.